# Hardware accelerated video decoding on Snapdragon, UbuntuOS

Tags: decoding

I use Snapdragon with Ubuntu OS,
And I need to find:
Hardware accelerated video decoding for H.264.

There are a lot of discussion about Snapdragon with Android,
But my case is Ubuntu OS.

Thanks.